# libmergestream.so: undefined symbol: XUnlockDisplay

Tags: dynamic, shared-libraries

I have looked around and tried my best, but I cant work this out:

I am compiling an application which will dynamically load user-created shared objects, such as libmergestream.so.

mergestream.cpp (from which libmergestream.so) is derived contains CImg library calls. I compile the shared object with `-lpthread -lX11 -lXext -lXrandr` flags.

Next, I build the second part of the application as an executable, and supply the same flags, and also the library: `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` via the linker flag.

When I run the application, the loading of shared object fails with the message:

```
Sun Jun  3 19:35:24 2012[1,6]<stdout>:0x7f46705e4180 ../DALProcesses/lib/libmergestream.so: undefined symbol: XUnlockDisplay
```

To be sure that I am not missing anything, I took a small CImg library example, and built it to an executable (no shared objects). It runs fine. For reference here, I'll call it CImgExample binary.

I look up symbols in CImgExample binary:

```
nm CImgExample | grep 'XUn'
         U XUngrabKeyboard
         U XUnlockDisplay
         U XUnmapWindow
```

The  binary itself has undefined symbols, and still I can get it to execute.

For ldd on CImgExample:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff988f5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4f08e61000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f4f08b2d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4f0882c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4f08532000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4f0831c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f07f5e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f090ab000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f4f07d40000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f07b3c000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f4f07938000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f4f07732000)
```

For comparison, here's the nm output for libmergestream.so:

```
nm libmergestream.so | grep 'XUn'
                 U XUngrabKeyboard
                 U XUnlockDisplay
                 U XUnmapWindow
```

and here's the ldd for the application (call it 'main') which will dynamically load libmergestream.so:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8dfff000)
libmpi.so.1 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa79c69a000)
libmpi_cxx.so.1 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa79c495000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa79c195000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa79bf7e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa79bbc1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa79c8e4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa79b8c7000)
```

I notice that these two library references are missing from 'main':

```
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f4f07938000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f4f07732000)
```

Funny thing is, I run the same build process for both the shared libraries and the 'main' on a Linux server, and everything goes well. It's my notebook that hates something, and I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you don't need the display capabilities of CImg in your library, you may disable the use for X11, just by placing a

```
#define cimg_display 0
```

just before the include of the "CImg.h" file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips. I will try out and get back with what I see.

Comment: Oh my God! After half an hour of trying everything this one finally worked!! I was using CUDA and NVCC had problems linking CImg to X11! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say, but it looks like you are using gcc on Linux. If so, try building libmergestream.so with the --no-undefined flag to ld (if you are passing it via the compiler driver, use -Wl,--no-undefined). This will fail the link for libmergestream.so unless all of the libraries required to satisfy its undefined symbols are provided on the link line. You will probably find that the link now fails with complaints about those same symbols. You can now add any required libraries to the library list for libmergestream.so until the link succeeds. Those new dependencies will be added to the 'needed' set for the library and loaded along with it at runtime.

This should work unless there are some symbols in libmergestream.so that are expected to be satisfied by the loading executable itself (which in that case should be compiled with --export-dynamic). If that is the case, you probably won't be able to get all the way to a completed link with --no-undefined, but you can use it to work out what libraries you still need to add: when the only symbols that fail the link are those provided by the executable, you can remove the --no-undefined and you should be OK at that point. But it is really better to abstract that support out into another shared library rather than depending on the executable. You should use --no-undefined if at all possible for libraries that you intend to load at runtime.